# How to debug Firefox crashes on Mac

Tags: macos, firefox, crash, plugins

I'm running Firefox 37.0.1 on OSX 10.10 and I'm always getting crashes. It's pretty much fresh out of the box, so this concerns me that there might be an underlying problem that's perhaps maybe not even Firefox.

After some searching, it seems that the best way to fix problems is with process of elimination with disabling plugins (and playing the waiting game between each crash). This is time consuming and unreliable (i.e. 3 days with no crash and only 1 plugin enabled doesn't guarantee anything)

I see that there is some reporting stored in this directory: `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Crash Reports`, but the binary format seems pretty useless to an end user.

The only thing I really have to go by is Mac's Problem Reporter. Is there anything I should be looking for in there? There must be a better way, right?

Comment: Navigating to `about:crashes` will list crash reports that have been submitted to Mozilla. If the crash occurred in a plug-in, it should be noted in the process type field. Are all the recorded crashes similar?